# Does mpi4py use Python Pickle

Tags: python, mpi

Based on the explanation on [mpi4py](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/mpi4py.pdf), I do not understand if it is using pickle, or it is more efficient than pickle.  Initially, the document states:

> The pickle (slower, written in pure Python) and cPickle (faster,
>   written in C) modules provide user-extensible facilities to serialize
>   generic Python objects using ASCII or binary formats. The marshal
>   module provides facilities to serialize built-in Python objects using
>   a binary format specific to Python, but independent of machine
>   architecture issues.

Based on this, it seems pickle is the slowest method.  The document then says:

> MPI for Python can communicate any built-in or used-defined Python
>   object taking advantage of the features provided by the mod:pickle
>   module.

So is MPI using the slowest option Pickle?  There is more text but I do not see a straightforward answer, maybe it is not straight forward implementation?  Am I totally mis-understanding what it is saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tries as hard as it can to use `cPickle`, but [falls back on `Pickle` if necessary](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/src/d81133e191fd523610602a4b0f59cf600f494831/src/MPI/msgpickle.pxi?at=master):

```
if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3:
    from pickle import dumps as PyPickle_dumps
    from pickle import loads as PyPickle_loads
    from pickle import DEFAULT_PROTOCOL as PyPickle_PROTOCOL
else:
    try:
        from cPickle import dumps as PyPickle_dumps
        from cPickle import loads as PyPickle_loads
        from cPickle import HIGHEST_PROTOCOL as PyPickle_PROTOCOL
    except ImportError:
        from pickle  import dumps as PyPickle_dumps
        from pickle  import loads as PyPickle_loads
        from pickle  import HIGHEST_PROTOCOL as PyPickle_PROTOCOL
```

Comment: So for a use of multiprocessing where on initialization of the processes unique data needs to be sent to each process and receive unique data from each one, mpi is the same efficiency?  (multiprocessing module uses pickle to send data if the data is not an array and can not be in shared memory, as I understand)

Answer (score 1):

As the pympi wrapper is based on MPI-2, for parallel I/O I would guess it only uses pickle to convert the data to an appropriate format (on each processes) before calling the MPI writing/communication functions behind the scenes. The line after the one you quotes says:

> Blockquote
>   These facilities will be routinely used to build binary representations of
>   objects to communicate (at sending processes), and restoring them back (at receiving processes).

The mpipy documentation suggest the use of numpy arrays instead of python data types whenever possible for efficiency. If you application is speed critical, I would recommend always using numpy arrays instead of python objects. The MPI 2.0 standard was introduced *mainly* to provide efficient parallel input output functionality. The use of MPI (written in c) would most likely be faster than either cpickle or pickle, especially when writing outputs on many processes.